# Run powershell commands atomically

Tags: powershell, atomic

I have 3 powershell commands that need to run synchronously, as I need to pass the output from the 1st to the 2nd, and so on. However if any fail I need to back out of all 3. Is there a cmdlet or technique, even, that will enable this behavior in powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap each of your commands in an object or a hashtable with a corresponding "rollback" action and a test:

```
$Commands = @(
  @{
    Action = { Set-Value $PathOne "newValue" }
    RollBack = { Set-Value $PathOne "oldValue" }
    Test = { Test-Something }
  }
  @{
    Action = { Set-Value $PathTwo "newValue" }
    RollBack = { Set-Value $PathTwo "oldValue" }
    Test = { Test-Something }
  }
)
```

Then use a `Stack<Scriptblock>` to keep track of actions that need to be executed in the event of a "roll-back"

```
$RollbackStack = [System.Collections.Generic.Stack[Scriptblock]]::new()

foreach($Command in $Commands){
  # Execute command
  & $Command.Action

  # Add rollback action to stack
  $RollbackStack.Push($Command.Rollback)

  # Test result, roll back if failed
  if(-not(& $Command.Test)){
    foreach($rollbackAction in $RollbackStack){
      & $rollbackAction
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, PowerShell commands do not support "backing out" or "rollback".  The Registry provider does support transactions (which would allow this kind of behavior), but only with operations involving the registry.

It might be possible to capture the state of things that you're updating in the commands and re-applying those states, but it would be a very manual process.